# Angular material inputs per row

Tags: angularjs, layout, flexbox, angular-material

In others frameworks I can specify the number of columns of an input. (With a grid of 12 columns per row).
I have a dynamic form. I don't know the number of inputs. I want to put the inputs according to size screen.
With actual layouts.... I only can specify "column" (one input per row) or "row" (all inputs in the same row).

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can refer to [this link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children) for dynamic layout design.

Comment: Thanks @Kunal Sharma. All I need was a layout-wrap. I found that in Extra Options of layout. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we need is set a flex value to each item and use layout-wrap to allow line break when flex use more than 100%.